# I am programming a discord bot in python, and need helping with joining and leaving vc's

Tags: python

**Here is my programming:**

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def join(ctx):
    if(ctx.author.voice):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel.id
        await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel.  You must be in a voice ")


@client.command(pass_context = True)
    async def leave(ctx):
        if (ctx.voice_client):
            await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
            await ctx.send("I left the voice channel")
        else:
            await ctx.send("I am not in a voice channel")
```

I have scoured around online and there are multiple versions what I am trying to do and I have tried all of the ones I have found but none to any avail.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The discord bot is not joining the vc.  The prefix I have assigned is '?'.  I type ?join on discord to get the bot join the vc but nothing happens.